# Javascript: Handling timers with multiple lengths of delay?

Tags: javascript, string, events, timer, intervals

Essentially what I'm trying to get this to do is display a list of words given by `#words` on a `textarea` `#display`. 
Each word is displayed one at a time, delayed by an amount of time designated by `getTextSpeed` which retrieves speed options chosen by the user.

For example, if the user selects 350 WPM as their desired speed for delay, then each word will have a delay of 117 ms. If they decide to change it to 400 WPM, the delay should decrease in real time dynamically to a delay of 150 ms without having to restart the display animation.

Additionally, if the word contains a character of punctuation, then the delay after the word is displayed should be doubled (ex: 117 ms to 234 ms) and the character should be removed. If there's multiple characters of punctuation, just one should be removed (ex: "..." --> "..")

Below are the relevant methods and my attempt at implementing this behavior. 
If you need the rest of the code (for testing purposes?), please see these pastebin links: [HTML](http://pastebin.com/R6gBShtX), [Javascript](http://pastebin.com/Z35MWHfy), [CSS](http://pastebin.com/XHaijbE4).

I haven't encountered any errors in the console, but the actual reflected behavior isn't what I want for sure.

There's a lag period at the beginning of starting the animation, which seems to vary based on the length of the input text, and the delay between each word is far, far longer than it should be. <s>Additionally, the punctuation doesn't appear to remove correctly.</s> EDIT #1: I just double-checked the `string.remove` syntax and you're supposed to put the actual `String`, not actually call the method from the `String` superclass.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

```
var timer;

function start() {
  var text = document.getElementById("words").value;
  var list = text.split(/\s+/);
  runDisplay(list, "display");
}

function runDisplay(data, id) {
    var reader = document.getElementById(id);
    var index = 0;
    var punctDelay = 0;    
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    if (data.length) {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
        var punctuation = [".", ",", ":", ";", "!", "?"];
        var word = data[index++];
        for (var j = 0; j < punctuation.length; j++) {
            if (!(word.indexOf(punctuation[j]) === -1)) {
                // word = String.replace(punctuation[j], ''); 
                word = word.replace(punctuation[j], ''); // see edit #1
                punctDelay = getTextSpeed();
            }
        }
        reader.innerHTML = word;
        index = index % data.length;
        }, getTextSpeed() + punctDelay); // change speed dynamically in real time
    }
}


function stop() {
  var display = document.getElementById("display");
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
  display.innerHTML = "";
}

function getTextSpeed() {
    var speeds = document.getElementById("speed");
    return speeds.options[speed.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you had already asked and I have already answered. What's wrong with this https://jsfiddle.net/grabantot/bsyvkb4d/3/ ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. For the scope of this assignment, I can only use `setInterval()` to implement the animation.

Comment: @user3450277, can you set up this problem in jsfiddle?

Comment: @user3450277 I doubt it's possible to get consistent animation using `setInterval`, `requestAnimationFrame` shoud be used to update document with such a high speed (1s/117 ms=8fps).

Comment: See this fiddle [delay is in square brackets] https://jsfiddle.net/grabantot/bsyvkb4d/4/